# How to multiSelect with selection manager in power bi custom visual

Tags: kendo-ui, powerbi, kendo-multiselect

I am using a kendo multi select in power bi custom visual but it appears that only the first selection is sticking.

My code is below:

```
            $("#myMultiSelect").kendoMultiSelect({
                dataTextField: "value",
                dataValueField: "identity",
                dataSource: viewModel.categories,
                change: function(e) {                 
                    var selectionDeffered = this.value().map(id => selectionManager.select(id, true));                       
                    if (this.value().length == 0)
                    {
                        selectionManager.clear()
                    }
               }
            });
```

A full gist with the kendo core is here:

https://gist.github.com/jcbowyer/5df55d4758a7614ca08d71eaf640fc57

Is there a simple way to achieve multi-select?  I may be making an obvious mistake but the chiclet sample is very complex and uses a different method called selectionhandler.  I am unclear how to user selection handler with kendo.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was not clearing previous selection.   The selection manager multiselect is working if one multi select is added.  I have not been able to get the mutliselect to work if multiple multi selects are added.